# How to upgrade Ruby on Fedora

Tags: ruby, rvm, fedora

I'm trying to upgrade Ruby to 1.8.7 on Fedora 13 (yes I know it's old) using [rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). I'm a little new to the Ruby world, but this is what I've done so far:

```
~$ yum -y install rubygem-rvm
...
~$ rvm-install
...
~$ rvm install 1.8.7
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #fetching 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p302 (already extracted)
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #configuring 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #compiling 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #installing 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #rubygems installing to ruby-1.8.7-p302
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem).
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #importing default gemsets (/usr/local/rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #complete 
~$ rvm use 1.8.7 --default
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302
~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2010-09-02 patchlevel 420) [x86_64-linux]
~$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302
~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2010-09-02 patchlevel 420) [x86_64-linux]
```

Everything seems to run fine, except Ruby 1.8.6 is still the default version.

What other steps am I missing to switch the default Ruby version to 1.8.7?

EDIT: It seems there's some really unintuitive behavior in rvm. If you don't install certain packages, then when you use rvm to install a specific Ruby version, rvm not only won't build or install that Ruby version, it won't even tell you it's not building Ruby. I noticed there was no bin directory in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302...which was unusually, being that Ruby is a binary and all. So I double checked the docs, and found a list of Fedora packages to install:

```
yum install -y bash curl git
yum install -y gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel
yum install -y iconv-devel
```

After those were installed, running `rvm install 1.8.7` correctly built a Ruby binary. Oddly, running `rvm use 1.8.7 --default` still doesn't update the default Ruby version, so I did:

```
cp /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby-1.8.6
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
ln -s /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: start a new shell after installing rvm?

Comment: Please append the output of `rvm info` to your question. By default RVM will install Rubyies into your `~/.rvm` so it appears you are doing a system-wide install. Is that your intent? Also, you should make sure that the RVM version is the latest, by doing `rvm get head`. Regarding loading packages, RVM and yum or apt-get is not an intuitive fit. I'd recommend installing using the directions at http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install because it's good to know what yum should have done. You can use `rvm requirements` to see what packages you need to install.

Comment: Did you append the path modifier `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function` to your `~/.bash_profile` and restart your terminal per the RVM installation docs?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to run `ruby -v` in the same shell where you ran `rvm use 1.8.7`.  I'm not sure what the `--default` option does so try leaving it off.

Comment: There's no difference in the result. I updated my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, this could be a few things. My guess is this though.

You might need to switch the linker to point at your new installation (the "shortcut" file in /usr/bin/). Find where you installed your new version of ruby. If the "ruby" linker in /usr/bin/ does not point to this new installation, make a new link by right-clicking on the ruby executable and make a link, put it /usr/bin/.

That's my only guess, I had this problem when I installed a new version of python.

Comment: I'm hesitant about making a manual symlink, because 1) it should have done something like that automatically, so I'd be ignoring something that's potentially broken with my use of rvm, and 2) I don't want to break my 1.8.6 install, because I might still need it.

Comment: Ahhh I see. That makes sense. When I installed python, it was the enthought distribution, so it wasn't through yum or anything like that. Best of luck.